# What is the best way to set a distance between Grid's or StackPanel's elements in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Grid with some elements inside:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="SomeText" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />

    <TextBlock Text="SomeText" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />

    <TextBlock Text="SomeText" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

The problem is that it looks tightly:

[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr2BI.png)

Margin property solves this problem, but I should to set this property to each element inside a grid. It is a hard way.

I want to obtain something like this setting margin property only once, but not for each element:

[what i want to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gexsV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `Margin` into an implicit `Style` in the `Grid.Resources`.

e.g.

```
<Style x:Key="MarginStyle" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MarginStyle}"/>
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource MarginStyle}"/>
```

---

You can also use an `ItemsControl` to apply a common style.

e.g.

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <!-- Panel without children here -->
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      </Grid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
  <!-- Children here -->
  <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Field 1: "/>
  <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Field 2: "/>
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Should I manually set a style for each element inside a grid?

Comment: @JohnWales: No, make it implicit by setting the `TargetType` and not the key.

Comment: This syntax is not right, you need to set TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"

Comment: @jimmyjambles: No you **do not**.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
But I have no reputation to plus you.

Comment: @JohnWales: That's fine, if you stick around long enough to earn that much you could come back if you want, you do not have any such obligation anyway (though it is common practice).

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a [style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx) and apply it to the elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this to the resources section of your grid

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

Alternatively, you could also use a vertical stackpanel populated with 2 column grids.

Then just style the grids