# Apply a style to multiple controls without using a key

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

In .NET WPF, I have the following XAML code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <CheckBox>Check 1</CheckBox>
    <TextBox>Some text...</TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

The controls **do not** have any margins applied to them.

Is it possible to apply a style to multiple controls (of different types) **without using a key** to set the style explicitly on each control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles are *not* inherited, you can base the subclasses' styles on that one though using `BasedOn`.

Another method in this case should be using an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) with an [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) set to this style.

There are examples for both methods in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11433552/546730).

Comment: This works but is a bit cumbersome since you have to write out a line of XAML code for each control type that you want the style applied to.

Comment: @AlexPi: Actually, in this case you should be able to make use of an `ItemsControl` (see edited answer).

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry, I misread the question before I wrote this out.** *My answer is useful if you want to style multiple checkboxes within the StackPanel.*

Implicitly style the entire application by placing this into your app.xaml's merged dictionaries.

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{DynamicResource YourBaseStyle}"/>
```

This also works on a much smaller scope. Reducing the scope to just that StackPanel simply requires that you add that same line of code to your `StackPanel.Resources` tag.